# Organising relational data in JSON which cannot be grouped together directly?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, data-structures, database-design

Beginner here, so please excuse me if this question is trivial, and kindly point me towards the correct resources.

Take this sentence:

> "This approach combines **the best of both worlds**."

Say I now want to highlight the bolded text whenever the user hovers over it. I know how to do it. But now take the following sentence:

> "**Speaking** of (in this case quite literally) **the devil**, ..."

Here, the words that belong together are apart, but I want to do the same thing. Highlight the bolded parts of the sentence, whenever the user hovers over any of the bolded parts.

Say I am generating these sentences from a JSON which I get from some backend. How would I best save this data in the JSON? That is, which highlights go together and which ones don't etc.?

```
{
 sentence: [
  { word: "This",
    highlight: false
  },
  { word: "approach",
    highlight: false
  },
  ...
  {
   word: "the best of both worlds",
   highlight: true
  }
 ]
}
```

? I am not even sure if this is a good solution. But suppose further I have multiple things I need to highlight in one single sentence, but keep them apart (so say 3 different expressions, each in its own colour). How would I best organise data like this (in the JSON that is!), which I cannot group together directly, but which nevertheless belongs together in some sense?

Comment: One strategy could be to think in terms of meta-data for your content. The question is how to apply the meta-data which is easy to extract and use. e.g.`{
sentence: "Speaking of (in this case quite literally) the devil, ...", highlight: [[0,7],[44,57]]'}`. Here I define my meta-data to highlight by character position of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to have an array of words, then iterate over the array.

```
{
 highlights: [
  {
      word: "This"
  },
  {
      word: "the best of both worlds"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: how would i put these together into the right order in the end though?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2020**: I would use a list of tuples and iterate through it sequentially.

```
[["Speaking", true], ["of (in this case quite literally)", false], ["the devil", true]]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.